# Как открыть хинт геобъекта?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Имеется коллекция ymaps.GeoObjectCollection экземпляра ymaps.Placemark.

Почему не открывается хинт методом place.hint.open(), если place метка из  коллекции, а получается только таким образом создать новый хинт, который остается на месте, когда карту передвигаешь?

```
  map.hint.open(
    place.geometry.getCoordinates(),
    "1" + place.properties.get("description") + ""
  );
```

Как открыть хинт из коллекции?

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, этим кодом вы создаете новый объект с заданными координатами.

Самый простой способ решить вашу задачу это создавать коллекцию меток в objectManager.ObjectCollection: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.ObjectCollection-docpage/

а затем открывать нужный хинт по id вашей метки через objectManager.Hint: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.Hint-docpage/#method_detail__open